# AutoHotKey script for switching option and command keys on Mac?

Tags: macbook, keyboard-layout, autohotkey

Does anyone have an AutoHotkey Script to switch to remap the command key to the option key and the control key to the command key on a Mac keyboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, AutoHotkey can be downloaded free here: http://www.autohotkey.com/

This script simply swaps the control and alt keys. After changing and saving the file, be sure to use **File->Reload Script** to apply.

```
LControl::LAlt

LAlt::LControl

RAlt::RControl

RControl::RAlt
```

If you want to rearrange the Windows key, the code would look like this:

```
LWin::Alt
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I believe you will need AutoHotkey_L for this, and not the regular AutoHotkey. See:

http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic70723.html

Comment: Any chance you could give an indication of the answer here, rather than just linking to it, in case the linked site ever disappears?